# Nautilus does not open executable files even after default behavior is changed

Tags: nautilus

I am running Ubuntu 16.10. I can run executable files through the command line using ./, but I cannot open any executable file through Nautilus, even after setting `Files`  ->  `Preferences` -> `Behavior` -> `Executable Text Files` to `Ask what to do`.  Is this a known bug with Nautilus in Ubuntu 16.10?

Comment: Mine works, not a bug. What happens exactly when you try to open the files?

Comment: I get Could not display "<filename>".  There is no application installed for "shared library" files.  Do you want to search for an application to open this file?

Comment: It doesn't sound like it is an executable file. Would you please tell us what file(s) are you trying to run exactly?

Comment: I compiled a simple c++ program with g++.  I am also unable to run shell commands from Nautilus.